# How export python project?

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

Let me explain elaborately what problem I am facing.
1. I am using Windows environment and pycharm IDE for development of python project.
2. As part of development I am going to use  several thrid party python packages say pexpect by installing through pip.
3. Once I am done with development I am going to use python project in Linux environment where I can't install any of these python packages.

So please suggest me way to export python project along with thrid party packages , so that without installing any of 3rd party packages I can run my project in Linux environment.

Comment: Just wanted to inform you that Visual Studio now supports python.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `virtualenv` when you are creating a python project with third party apps. virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments. You can export this project and run in any other environment(Linux, Windows, OSX).

Documentation - [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
Video - [Virtualenv Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk)

You also need to create a `requirement.txt` file which will contain your all third party apps. Once you are in virtual environment, you could use the below code:

`pip freeze > requirement.txt`  it will create a requirement.txt file.

For installing all the dependencies again, you need to use:
`pip install -r requirement.txt`